# Inference using robust statistics

Tags: inference, median, robust, mad

I'm simulating the overall usage of a cluster using historic deployment data.
Due to the nature of the simulation, there are some heavy points (i.e. very low overall usage). As a result, the variance blows up.

Naturally, I thought of using robust statistics (i.e. median and MAD) in order to account for the big spread of the data. However, I want to compare different "admission policies" for a cluster (i.e. compare different groups). Each group has a sample size of 100.

In the original paper (with theoretical data), the mean and standard error of the mean were used to compare the different groups. I want to do the same.

Is it scientifically correct to compare groups based on $\text{median}(X)\pm \text{MAD}(X)$?
Or should I use $\text{median}(X) \pm \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i - \text{median}(X)|$?

Comment: Basically it is up to you as long as you clearly state what the values mean. Boxplots could be an interesting option as well.

Comment: Yes boxplots could be interesting, I 'll give it a try. I also thought about tehe standard error of the median as a measure of the goodness of the estimate.

Comment: Good idea. "Notched" boxplots would show rough approximations of these standard errors as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what kind of 'admission criterion' you want.
If the original paper used the interval $\bar X \pm S/\sqrt{n},$ then that is something like a 68% confidence interval.

If you are happy using confidence intervals, then a reasonable approach
might be to use the nonparametric CI available in R from the one-sample
Wilcoxon procedure.

Suppose you have Laplace data which shows more outliers than does normal.
Then to get a 95% CI that is reasonably robust to outliers you could use R as
shown below. (You can choose any confidence level you like.)

**Nonparametric CIs for Laplace data.** I used a Laplace distribution with centered at $\mu = \eta = 15.$
The Wilcoxon interval includes this value. (And so does the t interval, which assumes *normal* data and has a length slightly inflated by the outliers.)

```
set.seed(2019)
x = rexp(100, .1) - rexp(100, .1) + 15
boxplot(x, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=19, notch=T)

wilcox.test(x, conf.int=T, conf.lev=.95)$conf.int
[1] 13.41728 17.74237
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95

t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 13.85243 19.03257
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

[image]

The notches in the sides of the box show a nonparametric confidence
interval, the level of which is calibrated for a comparison of two
such boxplots (see R documentation).

**Robust statistics.** If you want to use median and MAD, you could use R to get the intervals below, as you suggest in your Question:

```
median(x) + c(-1,1)*mad(x)
[1]  6.361976 23.546726
median(x) + c(-1,1)*mad(x, const=1)
[1]  9.158873 20.749829
```

If you use `mad` in R, you should read its documentation page to
understand the role of the default built-in constant multiplier,
which you can override as in my second interval above.

Then I suppose you would want to do simulations based on several possibly relevant long-tailed
distributions in order to understand the coverage properties of whatever
type of interval you choose to use.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I don't think nonparametric  methods are viable, as the "outliers" in our simulation come from a fault of our model (it has to do with the problem of artifically estimating the population of a server/cluster at any given time). Thus the outliers must not be considered as important. However I am interested in the approximative 68% CI using the standard error of the mean. Could you provide a link or explanation on this? - I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: (a) Rank-based nonparametric tests using ranks (such as Wilcoxon) are robust against outliers. (Even the hugest outlier only counts as highest-ranked observation.) IMHO: You should not dismiss them. (b) For $n=100,$ the interval $\bar X \pm (1.0)S/\sqrt{n}$ is a 68% CI for $\mu$ based on roughly normal data because 68% of probability in $\mathsf{T}(99)$ dist'n is btw $\pm1.$ // Please clarify exactly what you are doing: I understand you want some sort of interval. Can you say how a desirable interval is used to "admit" a "cluster"? And is a 'cluster' same as a 'group'.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look at the Willcox test. Maybe there is a clash of definitions here, a "cluster" refers to multiple servers bundled together (thus not a statistical term). We analyse different cluster admission policies and want to compare them, using the the overall usage (in terms of occupied cores). We have only 1 month worth of data and need to estimate a cluster that is already in use. To do so, we bootstrap start/left censored jobs . There are some artifacts in our data that may cause a very poor overall usage (if they are drawn too often).